# Finding tangent vectors to unit circle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am working on the following problem from Tu's *Introduction to Manifolds*.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWdc7.png]

I have been able to do (a), but (b) is causing me some troubles. My approach so far is as follows. Let $C$ be some smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $C(0) = p$ and $C'(0) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{x}}\Big|_p.$ Then

$$i_*\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{x}}\Big|_p\Big) = \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_0(i \circ C)(t) = \frac{\partial i}{\partial C}\Big|_{C(0)} \frac{\partial C}{\partial t}\Big|_0 = \frac{\partial i}{\partial C}\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{x}}\Big|_p.$$

I am unable to take this any further and it seems I am on the wrong track. Can anyone provide some hints?

Comment: You need a piece $B$ of the curve where the restriction of a coordinate function of the ambient space (e.g. $x$) to $C$ is a local coordinate. Then, in a neighbourhood $U$ of some point $p\in B$ you can proceed exactly as in a): you look at the restrictions of $x, y$ to $U\cap B$ and carry out exactly the same calculations. (What is $\frac{\partial i}{\partial C}$?)

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for your comment. Could you elaborate more on what $B$ is? I am a little unclear on it.

Comment: if $p$ is a point on $C$, you have to find a small piece of the curver around $p$, such that the restriction of one of the coordinate functions ($x$ or $y$) restricted to that piece, is a local coordinate on $C$. That piece of $C$ - which you have to choose - was called $B$ by me.

Comment: @Thomas So restrict to some $x$, requires $y$ to be $\sqrt{1-x^2}$? How would that help us compute $\frac{\partial i}{\partial C}$? If possible, can you write out the solution as answer?

Comment: Of course you cannot, in general, assume that $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ - that's specific for the upper half of the circle in the plane. But, if you assume that, in a neighbourhood of some point, the restriction $\bar{x}$ of $x$ to the curve is a local coordinate, you can write (in a possibly smaller neighbourhood) $y= f(x)$. With the exception of replacing $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ with $f(x)$, whatever calculation you did to proof a) should then carry over literally to the general case and yield (also, literally) the same result.

Comment: I prefer to not write an answer because I don't know Tu's book and there are too many different ways of introducing this topic. It is very likely that I will only produce more questions.

Comment: @Thomas I think I got it now, thank you for all your help and patience!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4537412.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Tu's use of "smooth curve" is ambiguous.

In section 8.6 (Curves in a Manifold) he defines it as a smooth map from an open interval to a manifold. But a smooth curve $u : (a,b) \to \mathbb R^2$ **is not** a submanifold $C \subset \mathbb R^2$. We could try to argue that the image of a smooth curve is a submanifold, but this is in general not true. The image may have corners (this is possible at points where $u'(\tau) = 0$) or self-intersections.

In Appendix B.2 (The Implicit Function Theorem) he gives a completely different interpretation when he says

> On a smooth curve $f (x,y) = 0$ in $\mathbb R^2$

Here $f$ is of course a smooth map and $C = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid f(x,y) = 0 \}$.

This makes clear that we should understand a smooth curve $C$ as a one-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$.

Now have a look to [Tangent vectors to a plane curve Tu #11.2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4537412). You will see that everything works exactly as for the circle $S^1$ under the assumption that $U$ is an open neighborhood of $p \in C$ such that $\bar x = x \mid_U : U \to \mathbb R$ is a local coordinate. The only difference is that we do not exlipicitly know what $\bar y = y \mid_U : U \to \mathbb R$ looks like. But this does not play any role, we still get the same formula as for $S^1$.

Note that in general there are points $p \in C$ which do not admit an open neigborhood $U$ such that $\bar x = x \mid_U : U \to \mathbb R$ is a local coordinate. For $S^1$ these are $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$. In such cases we can exchange the role of $x$ and $y$.